# How to open gif file in tkinter python?

Tags: python, macos, canvas, tkinter, gif

I want to open a gif file, but only a white square appears. I am using a mac. Here is my code:

```
def pic(aken, heigth, width, gif):
    name = Canvas(aken, width, height)
    name.create_image(height/2, width/2, image = gif)
    name.place(x=340, y=0)
def aken():
    aken = Tk()
    aken.geometry("800x600")
    sign = PhotoImage(file='CocaCola.gif')
    pic(aken, 120, 120, sign)
aken()
```

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Look this http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-do-my-tkinter-images-not-appear.htm

Answer (score 2):

This should be marked as a duplicate. The problem is that the image is being garbage collected, see this [Putting gif image in a canvas with Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424091/python-tkinter-gif-image-in-a-canvas) or look at the original advice here http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-do-my-tkinter-images-not-appear.htm